# jQuery search box auto complete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to create a auto complete search which get inputs  and prints result in a div.When i run my php code it gives correct results but it does not work with jquery, i can not print results which is about users input.My codes are like this,

My codes;

```
$('#search').on('input',function(e){


$('#search').autocomplete({

            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'complete.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                       name1: request.term,
                       type: 'name'
                    },
                     success: function( data ) {

                         response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item
                            }
                        }));
                       $("#showname").append(html);
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,

          });

    });
```

My Php Codes;

```
$name=$_POST['name1'];
$i=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from users where name like '".$name1."%'");
$data = array();
while($m=mysqli_fetch_assoc($i)){

  array_push($data, $m['name']);

 }
echo json_encode($data);
```

How can i search and print results according to user input ?

Thanks...

Comment: No errors in your console? I do not understand the html part. You are appending html to showname but html is not defined. Please explain.

Comment: there is a div which is called showname in my html,i try to print all results in this div.

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Comment: Here is my html code;<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
           
          </form> <div id="showname"></div>

Comment: I think you have some typo in your php code in second line $name1 replace it with $name.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
success: function( data ) {
   for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      $("#showname").append(data[i] + '<br>');
   }
}
```

to add it to your div. Add your own markup to your liking.